# Calling a previous saved value within a loop in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I am pretty new using R and I would really appreciate some input. I've created several subsets (one for each iteration) using  a loop. then I ran regressions using each subset/iteration and saved the coefficients (they are included in each subset/iteration as variables: single value for all rows in a column). what i would like to do is to save the coefficient obtained using the iteration i-1 in the iteration i (as i want to do predictions using the coefficients of the previous subset and the variables of the current subset)

Can someone help me with this.
Thanks.

here a reproducible example:

```
Data <- data.frame(
    X = sample(1:10),
    Y = sample(1:10)
)
Data$obs<-as.numeric(row.names(Data))
temp=NULL
obs=unique(Data$obs)
for (i in 2:length(obs)) {
    temp<-subset(Data, obs<=obs[i])
    ols <- lm(Y~X, data=temp)
    temp$intercept <-coef(summary(ols))["(Intercept)","Estimate"]
    temp$coefX <-coef(summary(ols))["X","Estimate"]

    #this is what i am trying to do
    temp$coefXprevious <- temp$coefX [i-1]

    write.csv(temp, paste(obs[i], ".csv", sep=""))
}
```

so for the last subset/iteration, I am getting:

```
X   Y   obs intercept   coefx   coefxprevious
8   5   1   9.8    -0.781818182 -0.781818182 
2   10  2   9.8    -0.781818182 -0.781818182 
10  1   3   9.8    -0.781818182 -0.781818182 
3   8   4   9.8    -0.781818182 -0.781818182 
9   2   5   9.8    -0.781818182 -0.781818182
5   4   6   9.8    -0.781818182 -0.781818182 
4   6   7   9.8    -0.781818182 -0.781818182 
7   3   8   9.8    -0.781818182 -0.781818182
6   9   9   9.8    -0.781818182 -0.781818182
1   7   10  9.8    -0.781818182 -0.781818182
```

this output is fine but the last column.
I would appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Are you getting an error/output that does not match these expectations when you run the code you pasted? If so, what are you **currently** getting? Does it run right now as is? It is good that you included what you need it to do, but stating exactly what the problem is would also be helpful.

Comment: Yes, for coefXprevious (which in the case of this 10th subset should call to the coefX of the 9th subset) i am getting the value of the  10th subset coefX value (-0.781818182) so the [i-1] is not working in the way i intended to. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a totally new `temp` on each iteration of the loop.  I think you want this:

```
Data <- data.frame(
  X = sample(1:10),
  Y = sample(1:10),
  intercept = rep(NA,10), coefX = rep(NA,10), coefXprevious = rep(NA,10)
)
Data$obs<-as.numeric(row.names(Data))

for (i in 2:length(obs)) {
  ols <- lm(Y~X, data=Data[Data$obs<=i,])
  Data$intercept[i] <-coef(summary(ols))["(Intercept)","Estimate"]
  Data$coefX[i] <-coef(summary(ols))["X","Estimate"]

  Data$coefXprevious[i] <- Data$coefX [i-1]

  write.csv(Data[Data$obs<-i,], paste(obs[i], ".csv", sep=""))
}
```

Which will make, as the last output (but why do you need the other outputs?):

```
    X  Y intercept      coefX coefXprevious obs

1   6  6        NA         NA            NA   1
2   9  4 10.000000 -0.6666667            NA   2
3   3  5  6.000000 -0.1666667    -0.6666667   3
4   8  9  5.071429  0.1428571    -0.1666667   4
5   2  2  2.580645  0.4677419     0.1428571   5
6   4  8  3.813559  0.3474576     0.4677419   6
7   1  1  2.363402  0.5592784     0.3474576   7
8   7  3  2.500000  0.4500000     0.5592784   8
9  10  7  2.500000  0.4500000     0.4500000   9
10  5 10  3.200000  0.4181818     0.4500000  10
```

Answer (score 0):

got it!!!

```
Data <- data.frame(X = sample(1:10),Y = sample(1:10))
Data$obs<-as.numeric(row.names(Data))

temp=NULL
temp2=NULL
obs=unique(Data$obs)

for (i in 8:length(obs)){
    temp1<-subset(Data, obs<=obs[i-1])
    temp2<-subset(Data, obs<=obs[i])
    ols1 <- lm(Y~X, data=temp1) 
    ols2 <- lm(Y~X, data=temp2) 

    temp2$coefx <-coef(summary(ols2))["X","Estimate"]
    temp2$coefxprev <- coef(summary(ols1))["X","Estimate"]
    temp2$predict <-predict(ols1,temp2)

write.csv(temp2, paste(obs[i], ".csv", sep=""))
}
```