# loop over a function in R

Tags: r, dataframe, function, for-loop

I have a function called `holt_filter` that does something and returns a data frame.  (function down below)

Its arguments are the original dataset, the initial date, the final date, and the forecast horizon.

so I would like to do something like this:

```
trends1 <- holt_filter(trends, initial_date="2003 Q1", final_date="2010 Q4", forecast_horizon=4)
trends1 <- trends1 %>%  rename_at(vars(-quarter), function(x) paste0(x,"t_11")) %>% relocate(quarter)

trends2 <- holt_filter(trends1, initial_date = "2003 Q1", final_date = "2011 Q4", forecast_horizon = 4)
trends2 <- trends2 %>% rename_with(~str_replace(., "t_11","t_12")) %>% relocate(quarter)

trends3 <- holt_filter(trends2, initial_date = "2003 Q1", final_date = "2012 Q4", forecast_horizon = 4)
trends3 <- trends3 %>% rename_with(~str_replace(., "t_12","t_13")) %>% relocate(quarter)

.
.
.
trendsi <- holt_filter(trends[i-1], initial_date="2003 Q1", final_date="2020 Q4"
```

Where `trends` is the original dataset.

I want to make a loop for this and generate multiple data frames, only varying the `final_date` argument. This is a vector for all the final dates I want.

```
dates <- c("2010 Q4","2011 Q4", "2012 Q4", "2013 Q4", "2014 Q4", "2015 Q4","2016 Q4","2017 Q4", "2018 Q4", "2019 Q4", "2020 Q4")
```

I think I need a double for loop, but I don't know how to use it.

Thanks in advance!

---

**`holt_filter` Function**

```
holt_filter <- function(data,initial_date, final_date, forecast_horizon){
  # Filter by date
  require(dplyr, zoo, forecast, lubridate)
  data <- data %>% 
    filter(quarter>= as.yearqtr(initial_date) & 
             quarter<=as.yearqtr(final_date))
  
  # Create a list with time series
  time_series <- lapply(select(data,-quarter), function(t) ts(t, 
                                                              start = c(year(as.yearqtr(initial_date)),quarter(as.yearqtr(initial_date))),
                                                              end=c(year(as.yearqtr(final_date)),quarter(as.yearqtr(final_date))),
                                                              frequency = 4 ))
  
  # Make the forecast
  holt <- lapply(time_series, holt, model="ZAN", damped=T, h=forecast_horizon)
  holt <- lapply(holt, forecast)
  
  
  # Convert to dataframe
  holt=holt %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
    select(contains("Point.Forecast")) %>% rename_with(~str_remove(.,".Point.Forecast")) %>% 
    rownames_to_column(var="quarter") %>% mutate(quarter=as.yearqtr(quarter)) 
  
  # Get a dataframe with original data and forecasted data
  data_out=data %>% bind_rows(data, holt)%>% 
    mutate(date=as.Date(quarter))
  
  data_out <- rbind(data, holt)
  
  # Get the output
  return(data_out)
}
```

**Data**

```
> dput(trends)
structure(list(quarter = structure(c(2003, 2003.25, 2003.5, 2003.75, 
2004, 2004.25, 2004.5, 2004.75, 2005, 2005.25, 2005.5, 2005.75, 
2006, 2006.25, 2006.5, 2006.75, 2007, 2007.25, 2007.5, 2007.75, 
2008, 2008.25, 2008.5, 2008.75, 2009, 2009.25, 2009.5, 2009.75, 
2010, 2010.25, 2010.5, 2010.75, 2011, 2011.25, 2011.5, 2011.75, 
2012, 2012.25, 2012.5, 2012.75, 2013, 2013.25, 2013.5, 2013.75, 
2014, 2014.25, 2014.5, 2014.75, 2015, 2015.25, 2015.5, 2015.75, 
2016, 2016.25, 2016.5, 2016.75, 2017, 2017.25, 2017.5, 2017.75, 
2018, 2018.25, 2018.5, 2018.75, 2019, 2019.25, 2019.5, 2019.75, 
2020), class = "yearqtr"), wti_t = structure(c(3.40327668190002, 
3.46458768844604, 3.52603244781494, 3.58761954307556, 3.6492030620575, 
3.71046233177185, 3.7709367275238, 3.83009004592896, 3.88737964630127, 
3.94229650497437, 3.9943859577179, 4.0432825088501, 4.08874273300171, 
4.13064479827881, 4.16898775100708, 4.20389080047607, 4.23551511764526, 
4.26393270492554, 4.28905296325684, 4.31069278717041, 4.32873487472534, 
4.3433198928833, 4.35502910614014, 4.36495780944824, 4.37446928024292, 
4.38469934463501, 4.39623260498047, 4.40915441513062, 4.42324638366699, 
4.4381251335144, 4.45328521728516, 4.46809720993042, 4.48182201385498, 
4.49368810653687, 4.50299024581909, 4.50911903381348, 4.51154518127441, 
4.50981569290161, 4.50357294082642, 4.4925274848938, 4.47642660140991, 
4.45505428314209, 4.42828607559204, 4.39618062973022, 4.35905838012695, 
4.3175573348999, 4.27268695831299, 4.22586345672607, 4.17881679534912, 
4.13334178924561, 4.09106779098511, 4.05335330963135, 4.02119064331055, 
3.99508142471313, 3.97501063346863, 3.96056962013245, 3.9511137008667, 
3.94587326049805, 3.94400477409363, 3.94459819793701, 3.94672346115112, 
3.94955539703369, 3.95252704620361, 3.95542335510254, 3.95836186408997, 
3.96169018745422, 3.96590781211853, 3.9716465473175, 3.9796416759491
), label = "wti trend component from bw filter", format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    cpiUSA_t = structure(c(5.20301055908203, 5.21056079864502, 
    5.21812438964844, 5.22571134567261, 5.23333024978638, 5.24098443984985, 
    5.24867153167725, 5.25638389587402, 5.26410722732544, 5.27182149887085, 
    5.27950143814087, 5.28711700439453, 5.29463863372803, 5.30203866958618, 
    5.30929279327393, 5.3163800239563, 5.32328176498413, 5.32997417449951, 
    5.3364315032959, 5.34262657165527, 5.34853792190552, 5.3541522026062, 
    5.3594765663147, 5.3645453453064, 5.36941576004028, 5.37415313720703, 
    5.37881469726562, 5.38344573974609, 5.38808059692383, 5.39274454116821, 
    5.39745187759399, 5.4022011756897, 5.40697526931763, 5.41174411773682, 
    5.41647005081177, 5.42111873626709, 5.4256591796875, 5.43006610870361, 
    5.43432235717773, 5.43841457366943, 5.44233655929565, 5.44608736038208, 
    5.44967412948608, 5.45310735702515, 5.45640134811401, 5.45957660675049, 
    5.4626612663269, 5.46569442749023, 5.46872186660767, 5.47179174423218, 
    5.47494649887085, 5.47822237014771, 5.48164844512939, 5.48524284362793, 
    5.48901319503784, 5.49295568466187, 5.49705791473389, 5.50130176544189, 
    5.50566673278809, 5.51012706756592, 5.51465368270874, 5.51922035217285, 
    5.52380275726318, 5.52838325500488, 5.53295278549194, 5.53750467300415, 
    5.54203939437866, 5.54656267166138, 5.55108642578125), label = "cpiUSA trend component from bw filter", format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    cpi_t = structure(c(4.15908050537109, 4.16563892364502, 4.17219924926758, 
    4.17877101898193, 4.18536996841431, 4.19202470779419, 4.1987738609314, 
    4.20566940307617, 4.21276378631592, 4.22010898590088, 4.22775220870972, 
    4.23573923110962, 4.24411106109619, 4.25290536880493, 4.26215982437134, 
    4.27190732955933, 4.28217172622681, 4.29296016693115, 4.30425643920898, 
    4.31601190567017, 4.32814264297485, 4.34053707122803, 4.35307264328003, 
    4.36563920974731, 4.37814998626709, 4.39054298400879, 4.40277862548828, 
    4.41483879089355, 4.42671871185303, 4.43842124938965, 4.44995546340942, 
    4.46133184432983, 4.47255373001099, 4.48361492156982, 4.49449920654297, 
    4.50518608093262, 4.5156512260437, 4.52587175369263, 4.53582954406738, 
    4.5455150604248, 4.55492401123047, 4.56405830383301, 4.57291889190674, 
    4.58150196075439, 4.58979034423828, 4.59775638580322, 4.6053638458252, 
    4.61257028579712, 4.61932849884033, 4.62559175491333, 4.63131904602051, 
    4.63648366928101, 4.64107227325439, 4.64508628845215, 4.64853954315186, 
    4.65145826339722, 4.65388011932373, 4.65585041046143, 4.65742254257202, 
    4.65865564346313, 4.65960931777954, 4.66034030914307, 4.66089868545532, 
    4.66132736206055, 4.66166257858276, 4.66193246841431, 4.66216087341309, 
    4.66236686706543, 4.66256237030029), label = "cpi trend component from bw filter", format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    rDep_t = structure(c(0.0359907001256943, 0.0349562615156174, 
    0.0339597687125206, 0.0330456756055355, 0.0322683714330196, 
    0.0316815711557865, 0.0313298515975475, 0.0312435291707516, 
    0.0314371325075626, 0.0319106914103031, 0.0326525755226612, 
    0.0336427949368954, 0.0348555110394955, 0.0362593047320843, 
    0.0378152914345264, 0.039474543184042, 0.0411769226193428, 
    0.0428547151386738, 0.044441495090723, 0.0458807088434696, 
    0.0471302084624767, 0.0481640547513962, 0.0489722304046154, 
    0.0495574288070202, 0.0499301664531231, 0.0501054525375366, 
    0.0501026771962643, 0.0499471835792065, 0.0496709644794464, 
    0.0493108406662941, 0.0489045232534409, 0.0484859794378281, 
    0.0480823814868927, 0.0477141067385674, 0.0473965927958488, 
    0.047142006456852, 0.0469598546624184, 0.0468570552766323, 
    0.0468380264937878, 0.046904768794775, 0.0470569133758545, 
    0.0472915954887867, 0.0476032570004463, 0.0479832850396633, 
    0.0484195314347744, 0.0488961711525917, 0.049394678324461, 
    0.0498958639800549, 0.0503816679120064, 0.0508363842964172, 
    0.0512480549514294, 0.0516093857586384, 0.0519173704087734, 
    0.052173275500536, 0.0523846074938774, 0.0525668896734715, 
    0.0527425780892372, 0.0529368445277214, 0.053172592073679, 
    0.0534672737121582, 0.0538319759070873, 0.0542714186012745, 
    0.0547842681407928, 0.0553636737167835, 0.055998433381319, 
    0.0566749982535839, 0.0573797486722469, 0.0581007860600948, 
    0.0588292218744755), label = "rDep trend component from bw filter", format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    cash_t = structure(c(8.59445476531982, 8.6219596862793, 8.64947891235352, 
    8.67704296112061, 8.70470333099365, 8.73252964019775, 8.76058483123779, 
    8.78891658782959, 8.81754112243652, 8.84644222259521, 8.8755578994751, 
    8.90479183197021, 8.93404579162598, 8.96323490142822, 8.99229717254639, 
    9.02118682861328, 9.04987525939941, 9.07836055755615, 9.10666942596436, 
    9.13485431671143, 9.16297626495361, 9.19108295440674, 9.21919250488281, 
    9.24728965759277, 9.27535820007324, 9.30342388153076, 9.33158397674561, 
    9.35999870300293, 9.38886737823486, 9.41841793060303, 9.44888019561768, 
    9.48047542572021, 9.5134105682373, 9.5478687286377, 9.58399200439453, 
    9.62187194824219, 9.66155052185059, 9.70302581787109, 9.74623775482178, 
    9.79106426239014, 9.83733463287354, 9.88484668731689, 9.93338012695312, 
    9.98270416259766, 10.0325679779053, 10.0826921463013, 10.1327524185181, 
    10.1823863983154, 10.2312145233154, 10.2788715362549, 10.325023651123, 
    10.3693971633911, 10.4117956161499, 10.4521017074585, 10.4902677536011, 
    10.5262994766235, 10.5602474212646, 10.5921945571899, 10.6222620010376, 
    10.6506004333496, 10.6773929595947, 10.7028455734253, 10.7271776199341, 
    10.7506122589111, 10.7733707427979, 10.7956571578979, 10.8176498413086, 
    10.839485168457, 10.8612518310547), label = "cash trend component from bw filter", format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    m1_t = structure(c(9.22379779815674, 9.26027679443359, 9.29678535461426, 
    9.33334350585938, 9.36996078491211, 9.40663719177246, 9.443359375, 
    9.4800968170166, 9.51680374145508, 9.55342960357666, 9.58992004394531, 
    9.62622833251953, 9.66231441497803, 9.69815921783447, 9.73377132415771, 
    9.76918315887451, 9.80445098876953, 9.83963680267334, 9.87478446960449, 
    9.90990543365479, 9.94497108459473, 9.97992897033691, 10.0147199630737, 
    10.0493049621582, 10.0836954116821, 10.1179599761963, 10.152195930481, 
    10.186484336853, 10.2208662033081, 10.2553453445435, 10.2898979187012, 
    10.3244867324829, 10.3590631484985, 10.3935880661011, 10.4280309677124, 
    10.4623680114746, 10.4965753555298, 10.5306234359741, 10.5644769668579, 
    10.5980854034424, 10.6313848495483, 10.6643133163452, 10.6968202590942, 
    10.728853225708, 10.7603549957275, 10.7912616729736, 10.8215074539185, 
    10.8510246276855, 10.8797674179077, 10.9077224731445, 10.9349050521851, 
    10.9613351821899, 10.9870223999023, 11.0119428634644, 11.0360431671143, 
    11.0592470169067, 11.0814762115479, 11.1026706695557, 11.1228103637695, 
    11.1419115066528, 11.1600294113159, 11.1772575378418, 11.1937198638916, 
    11.2095623016357, 11.2249279022217, 11.2399606704712, 11.254789352417, 
    11.2695121765137, 11.2841920852661), label = "m1 trend component from bw filter", format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    m2_t = structure(c(9.83384323120117, 9.87546920776367, 9.91716003417969, 
    9.95895099639893, 10.0008544921875, 10.042854309082, 10.0849170684814, 
    10.1269845962524, 10.1689834594727, 10.2108278274536, 10.2524347305298, 
    10.2937240600586, 10.3346252441406, 10.3750972747803, 10.4151372909546, 
    10.4547815322876, 10.4940977096558, 10.5331592559814, 10.5720272064209, 
    10.6107292175293, 10.6492700576782, 10.6876373291016, 10.7258367538452, 
    10.7639102935791, 10.8019552230835, 10.8401107788086, 10.8785133361816, 
    10.91725730896, 10.9563694000244, 10.9958200454712, 11.0355262756348, 
    11.0753688812256, 11.1151971817017, 11.1548376083374, 11.1941051483154, 
    11.2328214645386, 11.2708168029785, 11.3079528808594, 11.3441200256348, 
    11.379243850708, 11.413275718689, 11.4461879730225, 11.4779672622681, 
    11.5086030960083, 11.5380878448486, 11.5664224624634, 11.5936222076416, 
    11.6197309494019, 11.6448259353638, 11.6690330505371, 11.6925172805786, 
    11.715461730957, 11.7380275726318, 11.7603321075439, 11.7824335098267, 
    11.8043336868286, 11.826003074646, 11.8473997116089, 11.8684978485107, 
    11.8892812728882, 11.9097518920898, 11.9299297332764, 11.9498538970947, 
    11.9695749282837, 11.9891510009766, 12.0086326599121, 12.0280637741089, 
    12.0474739074707, 12.0668773651123), label = "m2 trend component from bw filter", format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    gdp_t = structure(c(16.1590557098389, 16.173246383667, 16.1874198913574, 
    16.2015361785889, 16.2155265808105, 16.2293128967285, 16.2428188323975, 
    16.2559795379639, 16.2687454223633, 16.281078338623, 16.2929668426514, 
    16.3044109344482, 16.3154201507568, 16.3260192871094, 16.3362445831299, 
    16.3461494445801, 16.3557968139648, 16.3652534484863, 16.3745727539062, 
    16.3838005065918, 16.3929653167725, 16.4020938873291, 16.4112186431885, 
    16.4203910827637, 16.4296894073486, 16.4392166137695, 16.4490852355957, 
    16.4593982696533, 16.4702224731445, 16.4815769195557, 16.4934349060059, 
    16.5057239532471, 16.5183372497559, 16.5311527252197, 16.5440330505371, 
    16.5568466186523, 16.5694675445557, 16.5817756652832, 16.5936641693115, 
    16.6050300598145, 16.6157875061035, 16.6258525848389, 16.6351490020752, 
    16.6436157226562, 16.651216506958, 16.6579303741455, 16.663761138916, 
    16.6687335968018, 16.672908782959, 16.6763858795166, 16.6792831420898, 
    16.6817378997803, 16.6838760375977, 16.6858062744141, 16.6876125335693, 
    16.6893463134766, 16.691032409668, 16.6926765441895, 16.6942653656006, 
    16.6957778930664, 16.6971950531006, 16.6984996795654, 16.6996784210205, 
    16.7007236480713, 16.7016372680664, 16.7024345397949, 16.7031402587891, 
    16.7037830352783, 16.7043933868408), label = "gdp trend component from bw filter", format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    gPub_t = structure(c(13.9551515579224, 13.9652347564697, 
    13.9753246307373, 13.9854335784912, 13.9955825805664, 14.0058078765869, 
    14.0161590576172, 14.0267000198364, 14.0375080108643, 14.0486764907837, 
    14.0603094100952, 14.0725126266479, 14.0853872299194, 14.0990133285522, 
    14.1134452819824, 14.1287088394165, 14.1448097229004, 14.1617469787598, 
    14.1795215606689, 14.1981239318848, 14.2174997329712, 14.2375469207764, 
    14.2581386566162, 14.2791500091553, 14.3004627227783, 14.321967124939, 
    14.3435697555542, 14.365216255188, 14.3868970870972, 14.4086408615112, 
    14.4304866790771, 14.4524555206299, 14.474536895752, 14.4966917037964, 
    14.5188484191895, 14.5409154891968, 14.5627708435059, 14.5842790603638, 
    14.6052865982056, 14.6256370544434, 14.645167350769, 14.6637287139893, 
    14.6812047958374, 14.6975116729736, 14.7125911712646, 14.7263965606689, 
    14.7388849258423, 14.7500410079956, 14.7599010467529, 14.7685575485229, 
    14.7761507034302, 14.782844543457, 14.7888031005859, 14.7941732406616, 
    14.7990770339966, 14.8036088943481, 14.8078298568726, 14.811767578125, 
    14.8154287338257, 14.8188028335571, 14.8218755722046, 14.824631690979, 
    14.8270664215088, 14.8291921615601, 14.8310508728027, 14.832706451416, 
    14.8342294692993, 14.8356819152832, 14.8371047973633), label = "gPub trend component from bw filter", format.stata = "%9.0g")), row.names = c(NA, 
-69L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Since you need a data frame from (i-1)th iteration, does this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25415313/calling-a-previous-saved-value-within-a-loop-in-r) answer your question?

Comment: @RusiruAdithyaSamarasinghe not really

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question, but I'll take my best shot at it. From what I can gather, I think you only need one loop, and I think you would be better off making a list of dataframes. Maybe something like this:

```
trends_list <- list()
for(i in 1:length(dates)){
    f_date <- dates[i]
    if(i==1) prev_trend <- trends
    else prev_trend <- trends_list[dates[i-1]]
    trends_list[f_date] <- holt_filter(prev_trend, initial_date="2003 Q1", final_date=f_date, forecast_horizon=4)
    trends_list[f_date] <- trends_list[f_date] %>% rename_at(vars(-quarter), function(x) paste0(x,"t_",10+i)) %>% relocate(quarter)
}
```

Then, you can get whatever dataframe you want by looking at the list. That is `trends_list["2010 Q4"]` for the first one etc.

EDIT: I fixed the function somewhat, and I think I got the loop to work. You should be able to copy and paste the following code and it should work

```
trends_list <- list()
for(i in 1:length(dates)){
      f_date <- dates[i]
      if(i==1) {prev_trend <- trends
      }else {prev_trend <- trends_list[[dates[i-1]]]}
      trends_list[[f_date]] <- holt_filter(prev_trend, initial_date="2003 Q1", final_date=f_date, forecast_horizon=4)
    }

#Adding the suffixes afterwards so they do not stack on top of each other
for(i in 1:length(dates)){
      f_date <- dates[i]
      trends_list[[f_date]] <- trends_list[[f_date]] %>% 
rename_at(vars(-quarter), function(x) paste0(x,"t_",10+i)) %>% 
relocate(quarter)
      
    }
```

Comment: omg i based your idea on what i was trying. So i added a list out of the loop. but then did this:```for (x in dates) {

  df <- holt_filter(trends, initial_date = "2003 Q1", final_date = x, forecast_horizon = 4)
  
  trends_list[[x]] <- df}
  ```

Comment: But there's a problem when you do the `1:lenght` part, because `holt_filter` function uses time series, so it has to loop over strings

Comment: I think using an int is more convenient here because it allows you to both figure out which trend dataFrame you should be using, and it also allows you to select the string. As you can see, I selected the string using `f_date <- dates[i]` and then used `f_date` in the `holt_filter` function

Comment: however when i run your code it gets me an error ):

Comment: `Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : 
  no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "list"
In addition: Warning message:
In trends_list[f_date] <- holt_filter(prev_trend, initial_date = "2003 Q1",  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`

Comment: I just fixed it, I think the code I gave you should work.

Answer (score 0):

So what I did based on the last answer is:

```
trends_list <- list()

for (x in dates){
  df <- holt_filter(trends, initial_date = "2003 Q1", final_date = x, forecast_horizon = 4)
  for(i in 1:length(dates)){
    df <- df %>% rename_at(vars(-quarter), function(x) paste0(x,"t_",10+i)) %>% relocate(quarter)
  }

  trends_list[[x]] <- df
}
```

However, I keep struggling with the name loops.

Here is a screenshot of what I got after running this code.

[image]